# $X_t$ for Ample Sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ Affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, $\mathcal{L}$ an invertible sheaf and $t \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{L})$ a global section.

Consider the subset $X_t = \{x \in X \vert (t)_x \neq 0 \}$, or equivalently $(t)_x \not \in m_x\mathcal{L}_{X,x}$.

How to prove that if $\mathcal{L}$ ample (therefore the $X_s, s \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}), n \ge 1$ form a base of topology of $X$),

then $X_t$ affine.

Ideas: I have to show that $\Gamma(X_t,\mathcal{O}_X)$ respects the localisations at prime ideals $\mathbb{p} \subset \Gamma(X_t,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Therefore I have to show that $\mathcal{O}_{X, p} = \Gamma(X_t,\mathcal{O}_X)_p$ holds. No idea how to make next steps.

Comment: This not true for all $t$. Take $t=1$ on a quasi-affine scheme, then $X_t = X$ and this might not be affine. It is true that such a $t$ exists and that we can cover $X$ with such affine $X_t$'s if we allow to take powers.

Comment: ...and that's just the definition of beeing ample?

Comment: It is a consequence of the equivalent definition, you gave us. By your definition, if $x \in X$ and $U \ni x$ an affine neighbourhood which trivializes $\mathcal L$, we find some $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal L^n)$ with $x \in X_s \subset U$. But then $X_s$ is affine because it is a principal open of the affine scheme $U$, namely it is the principal open corresponding to the ring element, which corresponds to $s$ under the said trivialization.